# Installing font and making Windows aware

Tags: windows, winapi, fonts

I have a function below which installs a font (`.ttf`) into Windows by copying it into the Windows font folder and then triggering the `WM_FONTCHANGE` message. However, that font does not immediately become visible across Windows Explorer.

After running this, when I open Fonts through the Control Panel, my font does not show there. And when I open `C:\Windows\Fonts\` it does not show there either.

However I can confirm that my `.ttf` file is really there. Navigating here with the Command Prompt, I can see my font file. When I open the Character Map utility, my font is listed here. And the font is usable in my application. I have to restart `explorer.exe` to get it to show within the Windows Explorer views. I've even tried running my app as administrator (elevated), and still no luck.

I thought the `WM_FONTCHANGE` message was supposed to take care of this but apparently this is not doing the trick.

What am I missing in this Font Installation to make sure Windows is aware of it?

```
uses
  SysUtils, ShlObj, ComObj, ActiveX;

function SystemDir(Handle: THandle; Folder: Integer): String;
var
  R: HRESULT;
  PIDL: PItemIDList;
  Path: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
begin
  Result:= '';
  R:= SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(Handle, Folder, PIDL);
  if R = S_OK then begin
    if SHGetPathFromIDList(PIDL, Path) then
      Result:= StrPas(Path);
  end;
end;

function InstallFont(Handle: THandle; const Filename: String): Boolean;
var
  Dir, FN: String;
begin
  Result:= False;
  FN:= ExtractFileName(Filename);
  Dir:= IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(SystemDir(Handle, CSIDL_FONTS));
  Result:= FileExists(Filename);
  if Result then begin
    Result:= CopyFile(PChar(Filename), PChar(Dir + FN), False);
  end;
  SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, 0, 0);
end;
```

Usage:

```
Result:= InstallFont(Application.Handle, 'C:\MyTestFont.ttf');
```

**UPDATE**

It was suggested in the comments of an answer below to install the font via the shell instead of Windows API. So, I wrote this function to essentially accomplish the same:

```
function InstallFont2(Handle: THandle; const Filename: String): Boolean;
var
  R: HINST;
begin
  Result:= False;
  R:= ShellExecuteW(Handle, 'install', PWideChar(Filename), nil, nil, SW_HIDE);
  Result:= R > 32;
end;
```

However this too is problematic. The return value is `31` (indicating an error) and when I call `GetLastError` it tells me `1155` ("No application is associated with the specified file for this operation.")

I also tried the particular resolution in the answer below, but to no avail. I both used `AddFontResource` and written the appropriate registry key - while trying combinations of uninstalling/restarting/retrying with this font installation.

Comment: Make this the last time you ever call `ShellExecute`. Its error handling is useless. Why did you call `GetLastError`? Where does it say to do that in the documentation. `ShellExecute` only exists for compat with old programs. You are expected to call `ShellExecuteEx`. Anyway, don't you need to be elevated to do this?

Comment: `ShellExecute` can execute verbs defined on file classes. It fails in this case because the file class for true-type fonts (`ttffile`) doesn't define verbs directly on itself. It does implement `IContextMenu` and inject additional items into the right-click menu, and one of those items is verb `"install"`, but that can only be invoked via `IContextMenu::InvokeCommand`. `ShellExecute` doesn't know how to do this.

This probably isn't what you want anyway, though, as there is no way to shut off the user interaction, including prompting to delete the font if it already exists etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`WM_FONTCHANGE` only notifies applications of a new font in the system, but it doesn't actually tell the system what the new font is.

Before sending `WM_FONTCHANGE` you need to call [`AddFontResource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to add the font to the system font table. If you want the font to remain after a reboot, you also need to add an entry to the registry key **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts** (see the documentation for `AddFontResource` for more information).

Comment: o0o... I thought `AddFontResource` was only per-process instance.

Comment: @JerryDodge: you are thinking of [`AddFontMemResourceEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183325.aspx) instead: "A font that is added by `AddFontMemResourceEx` is always private to the process that made the call and is not enumerable."  Or maybe [`AddFontResourceEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183327.aspx) with the `FR_PRIVATE` flag: "Specifies that only the process that called the `AddFontResourceEx` function can use this font."

Comment: Haven't accepted yet because I'm still not having any luck with it... Still trying to figure out where I'm going wrong. I've both called `AddFontResource` successfully and written this registry entry successfully before calling this message, and Windows Explorer still doesn't want to show it. Not to mention having to detect what name to register it under... When I install it via other software (including the file itself) it installs fine. I guess there's still some missing pieces here.

Comment: An even easier method is to just use the shell to install it, using `ShellExecuteEx` with the `"install"` verb.

Comment: Using `ShellExecuteW(Handle, 'install', PWideChar(Filename), nil, nil, SW_HIDE)` is returning `31` (indicating an error) and `GetLastError` is telling me `1155` ("No application is associated with the specified file for this operation."). Hmmm this doesn't seem right... Does it have to be via `ShellExecuteEx`?

Answer (score 2):

I have just traced through exactly what Windows 7 does when it installs a font. Here is a summary:

- If the font is a true-type font and its name doesn't already end with `" (TrueType)"` then it appends this.
- If the font already exists, it can uninstall it in order to reinstall it:

  - It calls RemoveFontResourceW.
  - The registry entry describing the font, if any, is deleted out of `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts`.
- It takes the filename you are trying to install, and if that already exists in the Fonts directory, then it scans for a unique filename by repeatedly adding 1 to a counter and then formatting `"basename_X.ttf"` where X is in hexadecimal. So e.g. if `"myfont_1.ttf"` through `"myfont_9.ttf"` already exist, then it will try `"myfont_A.ttf"` next.
- It copies the file you supplied to this free filename it has identified.
- It calls `AddFontResourceW` on the target path.
- It writes an entry to `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts` based on the "(TrueType)"-qualified name of your font whose value is the target filename without path.
- It does a thing I couldn't quite figure out, creating a PropertyStore and putting a bunch of values into it. I'm not sure what exactly it does with the resulting property store, but it calls it a `FID`.
- It waits for 2 seconds by calling `Sleep`.
- It calls `PostMessageW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGSCHANGE, NULL, L"fonts")`
- It calls `PostMessageW(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_FONTCHANGE, NULL, NULL)`
- It calls `SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(CSIDL_FONTS)` and then passes the resulting `IDLIST` into `SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEDIR, SHCNF_IDLIST, idlist, NULL)`.

I suspect it is these latter three that are crucial in getting the system to recognize the new font in other applications and in the Fonts folder.